# Drupal Google Code Browser

Tags: svn, drupal, drupal-7, repository, google-code

I am building a website for a team that I am on. We have some code up on Google code, and we want to make it easily accessible for download (upload would be great too, but not necessary) to authorized users of our team through our central command website.

I am looking for a drupal module to do this, but I cant seem to come up with any solutions. Is there a module out there to accomplish this, or some other workaround that I have not found?

We are using drupal version 7.

Thank you!

Comment: What about wget-style or cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just linked to google code, inside of a node and then restriced the addresses that "frame" visited.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you would probably want to use something like Git, and/or also Drush.

- https://github.com
- http://drupal.org/project/drush

Comment: Those are more for putting drupal into a SVN.